# Show the inequality

Tags: inequality

Probably duplicate ,

> If $x$ and $y$ are non- negative real numbers and $x+y=2$ then prove that $x³y³(x³+y³) \leq 2$

I tried it by AM GM inequality but not getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$F(x)=x^3(2-x)^3(x^3+(2-x)^3)$$
Then $$F'(x)=6(1-x)[x^2(2-x)^2(x^3+(2-x)^3)+2x^3(2-x)^3]$$
and
$$F'(x)>0,when\, x\in [0,1] ,F'(x)<0,when\,x\in [1,2]$$
Hence,
$$x^3y^3(x^3+y^3)=F(x)\le F(1)=2,x\in [0,2]$$
The proof is completed.

Comment: Thank you very much .